# How do I get the `NULL` data from this join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'd like to join two table:

```
t_act
ID_ACT   ACT
1        ACT1
2        ACT2
3        ACT3
4        ACT4
5        ACT5

t_work
NO   ID_WORK   ID_ACT   ACT
1         A         1   ACT1
2         A         3   ACT3
```

The output I looking for is:

```
NO    ID_WORK    ID_ACT    ACT
1           A         1    ACT1
2           A         2    NULL
3           A         3    ACT3
3           A         4    NULL
4           A         5    NULL
```

I've used LEFT or RIGHT JOIN but it;s not produced the desired output.

My query:
`SELECT * FROM t_work LEFT OUTER JOIN t_act ON t_work.ID_ACT = t_act.ID_ACT`

Comment: A `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOIN` is what you should be using here. Please show us the query you wrote and then someone will be able to point out your mistake.

Comment: we can't fix code we can't see. Please show us what you tried, and what the output was.

Comment: I've add my current query.

Comment: what is the primary key of `t_work` ? a combination of `ID` and `ID_ACT` ? What's the point storing in `t_work` the `ACT` since it's already present in the `t_act` ?

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure your desired output makes much sense...how are you expecting the "A" values to come when there is no row matching in the "t_work" table...e.g. for ID_ACT = 2 there is no matching row in t_work. It cannot know to put an "A" there, because that value comes from a table where there is no matching row. It's also not clear if the tables are properly normalised...you seem to be storing the ACT value twice, even though it's appears not to be a foreign or primary key in either table. What does this data actually represent? Possibly the real problem is a bad table design.

Comment: @ashura91 No, this is not possible. In your example, the primary key is duplicated which is not possible.

Comment: @ADyson the A is not necessary. Of course this is a simplified example from my current table

Comment: @ashura91 if it's not necessary then why did you state it as desired output? You're just confusing us and making the problem seem harder than it is. Please be clear about what you actually want. And as Cid says, your ID cannot be the primary key in the t_work table...primary key values must be unique. Check that you actually understand your own schema...

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I think I forgot 1 column.  The `NO` column

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]--including DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. "I'd like to join two tables" does not tell us what you want. How do you expect us to know? (Rhetorical.) Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly say what you want your result to be in terms of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Good:

```
mysql> select * from t_act;
+--------+------+
| ID_ACT | ACT  |
+--------+------+
|      1 | ACT1 |
|      2 | ACT2 |
|      3 | ACT3 |
|      4 | ACT4 |
|      5 | ACT5 |
+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t_work;
+----+---------+--------+------+
| NO | ID_WORK | ID_ACT | ACT  |
+----+---------+--------+------+
|  1 | A       |      1 | ACT1 |
|  2 | A       |      3 | ACT3 |
+----+---------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

OUTPUT:

```
mysql> select a.NO,a.ID_WORK, b.ID_ACT, a.ACT from t_act as b left     
join t_work as a using  (ID_ACT) order by ID_ACT;
+------+---------+--------+------+
| NO   | ID_WORK | ID_ACT | ACT  |
+------+---------+--------+------+
|    1 | A       |      1 | ACT1 |
| NULL | NULL    |      2 | NULL |
|    2 | A       |      3 | ACT3 |
| NULL | NULL    |      4 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL    |      5 | NULL |
+------+---------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But I'm not sure about the NO and ID_WORK column in your desired output.

ID_ACT 2 is not present in table t_work. So, you will have NULL under NO / ID_WORK columns in the desired Output too. Are you sure, you'll have VALUES on those columns??

Comment: I've use LEFT JOIN. But, the output is not the one I desired and yes, the A is not  needed.

Comment: Ususally left/right join will do the trick. But, it's not in this case. I also curious

Comment: What's the result for the above query ?

Comment: sorry, I think I forgot 1 column. The NO column

Comment: Looks fine. I just created sample tables and executed the Query. I have updated the answer too.

Comment: @Krishnakumar, your output is not matching what OP wants :) and his question he already mentioned that he tried with left and right outer join - then in which perspective your query is different that OP's one

Comment: @fa06 I did ask him about the NO / ID_WORK columns. Obviously, they won't be filled out with VALUES since they don't have entries into the joined table.

Comment: @fa06 Look at his first comment in the answer. He says 'A' is not needed